# how to prevent happens-before in synchronized code in java?

Tags: java, multithreading, synchronization

I only have one synchronized method. The purpose of which is to prevent two threads from updating the same table which will surely cause an exception. I am trying to update one table whose data is from a huge external db. Before updating my table, I have to do some filtering and cleaning up which takes a lot of time. I created multiple threads so that I can divide the tasks and update the table fast. The plan/design is as soon as one thread is finished with cleaning up the data it should update my table while the other threads are still working on cleaning up. However, in my sample code, the threads are overwriting the values because of happens-before relationship. I don't want the threads to share the data i just want them to not update while some thread is updating. If you can see in my code below, I have created a list which i use to loop thru to create a thread and pass each data from the list. However, in the result, the thread 1, 4 and 5 are using the same programId in the Synchronized method when they should not be. Can anyone help to prevent this so that each thread will have a unique Id in the Synchronized code?

Here is my code:

```
public Class HomeController{

    List<String> programList = new ArrayList<String>();
    programList.add("xxx");
    programList.add("yyy");
    for(String programId: programList){

    System.out.println("programId Controller is " + programId);
    //for each program Id create a thread
    runnable.setProgramId(programId);
    taskExecutor.execute(runnable);
    }

}

public class TestRunnable implements Runnable{

    public void run(){
            String threadName = Thread.currentThread().getName();
            System.out.println("threadName and programId Runnable are " + threadName +"--"+ programId);
            TestSynchronized testSynchronized = new TestSynchronized();
            testSynchronized.updateTable(programId);
            }
    }

}

public class TestSynchronized{

    private volatile boolean isLocked = false; 

    public synchronized void updateTable(String programId){

            while(isLocked) {
                 try {
                     wait();
                 } catch (InterruptedException e) {}
            }
            isLocked=true;
            String threadName = Thread.currentThread().getName();
            System.out.println("threadName and programId Synchronized are " + threadName +"--"+ programId);

            isLocked=false;
            notify();
    }
}
```

Here is the result:

```
programId Controller is 23022490857
programId Controller is 23022491963
threadName and programId Runnable are taskExecutor-1--23022490857
programId Controller is 23022492068
threadName and programId Runnable are taskExecutor-2--23022491963
programId Controller is 23022492300
threadName and programId Synchronized are taskExecutor-1--23022491963
programId Controller is 23022495561
threadName and programId Runnable are taskExecutor-3--23022492068
threadName and programId Synchronized are taskExecutor-2--23022492068
programId Controller is 38416827134
threadName and programId Synchronized are taskExecutor-3--23022492300
threadName and programId Runnable are taskExecutor-4--23022492300
threadName and programId Runnable are taskExecutor-1--38416827134
threadName and programId Synchronized are taskExecutor-1--38416827134
threadName and programId Runnable are taskExecutor-5--23022495561
threadName and programId Synchronized are taskExecutor-4--38416827134
threadName and programId Synchronized are taskExecutor-5--38416827134
```

Comment: You should create one test synchronized, and a TestRunnable for each programId. You should not reuse the same TestRunnable.

Comment: thanks Mark for the quick reply. How can I prevent two threads from updating the same table at the same time as it will cause an exception?

Comment: Please ask the actual question you have, because that problem is not really related to the problems of the code you show.

Comment: a simple `synchronized(theSharedTable)` block can only be entered by 1 thread.

Comment: hi zapl, that is correct and that is actually what is happening in my code. However, because of happens-before scenario, the programId is overwritten along the way.

Comment: The programId is overwritten because you - based on the shown code - are reusing the same runnable for every programId, so the last one wins.

Comment: yes, i am reusing the same runnable. However, if i understand threading correctly, when you create a thread using runnable, it doesn't matter if another thread is reusing it with another value. It doesn't overwrite the value of the earlier Runnable as it is in another thread.

Comment: That is not how it works. As the `Runnable` instance is **the same** each thread is sharing the **fields** of that runnable. So the `programId` field can be overwritten before the thread has even started, or it can be changed between you doing the `println` and calling `updateTable`, etc. A `Runnable` is only reusable for multiple threads if it has no state, or the state is immutable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have two problems in the code shown:

1. You are reusing the same `TestRunnable` for each thread, this means that the `programId` is (or can be) overwritten before you use it.
2. You are creating a new `TestSynchronized` for each thread, so you have **no** thread safety at all.

What you need to do is:

1. Create one, and only one `TestSynchronized`
2. Create a **new** `TestRunnable` for each programId. Pass the programId and the shared `TestSynchronized` in the constructor.

Comment: Mark, thanks. It solved my problem. Thanks for sharing your knowledge.

Answer (score 1):

How many copies of `TestSynchronized` do you have? If it's more than one you're going to not get any synchronization.

Separate the synchronization with the actual code execution.

Comment: hi Tassos, each thread has its own instance but they cannot use the synchronized method at the same time. So in essence, they are sharing that method even if they have different instances.

Comment: You are mixing up two different things @user3067802 ... The method (code) is the same for both instances. But synchronization deals with threads ... so two thread can enter the same synchronized method given they do it on two different instances of that class the method is a part of.

Comment: hi Fildor, can you tell me which one is causing the problem? I have separated Runnable and the Synchronized code to be sure that each code is doing its own job.

Comment: You will either have one single `Runnable`, or two with an extra synchronization lock. If you use two runnables, each one will have their own lock, which kind of defeats the point of synchronization. Keep in mind that the `synchronized` keyword in the method is effectively a wrapper around `synchronzed(this){...}`; two runnables means two different values for `this`.

Comment: thanks for the clarification. I wish i can vote for the correct answer multiple times.

Answer (score 1):

You need to understand how object monitors work.  `synchronized` will block access to the resource, the object reference.  In this case you create a new `TestSynchronized` for each Thread.  Since synchronizing works on the object reference, you are essentially not blocking anywhere.

If you create one `TestSynchronized` and pass it to each `TestRunnable` you will get the output you expect.

Answer (score 1):

> ...the threads are overwriting the values because of happens-before relationship.

Not really answering your question but, I think you misunderstand the meaning of "Happens Before".

The Java Language Spec (JLS) uses the phrase "happens before" in describing certain guarantees that you can use in reasoning about how your program will behave.  For example, the JLS says that leaving a `synchronized(o)` block in one thread *happens before* another thread synchronizes on same object `o`.  That's how you know that if thread A enters the block, updates some variable, and then leaves the block, and then thread B enters the block; thread B is guaranteed to see what thread A stored in the variable.

But here's what it doesn't tell you:

It doesn't tell you which thread is going to get *in* to the synchronized block first.  If it's possible for two threads in your program to attempt to synchronize on the same object at the same time, then you've got a *data race*.  One thread is going to win, the other is going to lose, and there's no way to know which one will win.

If you've got a data race in your program, and it matters which thread wins, then you've got a *defect*.

It's up to you to either change your design so that it doesn't matter which thread wins, or change your design to use some kind of higher-level synchronization (queues, semaphores, barriers, etc.) to insure that the *right* thread wins.